# How to efficiently subdivide large block into many small blocks sized power of 2 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, malloc

Building off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66253424/how-to-efficiently-segment-a-large-block-of-predefined-size-into-smaller-blocks/66327199#66327199):

```js
function allocate(bits) {
  if ((bits & (bits - 1)) != 0) {
      throw "Parameter is not a power of 2";
  }

  if (bits < 128 || bits > 4194304) {
      throw "Bits required out of range";
  }

  var startBinIndex = Math.log2(bits >> 7);
  var lastBin = BIN_OF_BINS.length - 1;

  for (var binIndex = startBinIndex; binIndex <= lastBin ; binIndex++) {
      var bin = BIN_OF_BINS[binIndex];

      //
      // We have found a bin that is not empty...
      //
      if (bin.length != 0) {
          //
          // Calculate amount of memory this bin takes up
          //
          var thisBinMemorySize = (128 << binIndex);
          var lastBinOfBinsIndex = bin.length - 1;
          var binBlock = bin[lastBinOfBinsIndex];
          var memoryAddress = binBlock.start;


          //
          // We are going to return this block
          //
          var allocatedMemoryBlock = {start : memoryAddress, count : 1};

          //
          // Before we return the above block, we need to remove the block if count is 1 otherwise decrease count and adjust memory start pointer by bin size
          //
          if (binBlock.count == 1) {
              bin.pop();
          }
          else {
              binBlock.count--;
              binBlock.start += thisBinMemorySize;
          }

          //
          // if we want 1024 bits and it takes it from bin 15, we simply subtract 1024 from 4194304 which gives us 4193280
          // if we then populate bin 3 (1024 bits) onward, until bin 14, the exact number we end up populating those bins with is 4183280
          //
          var remainingUnsedMemory = thisBinMemorySize - bits;
          var adjustmentSize = bits;
          while (remainingUnsedMemory != 0) {
              memoryAddress += adjustmentSize;

              BIN_OF_BINS[startBinIndex].push({start : memoryAddress, count : 1});
              startBinIndex++;
              remainingUnsedMemory -= bits;
              adjustmentSize = bits;
              bits <<= 1;
          }

          return allocatedMemoryBlock;
      }
  }
  return null; // out of memory...
}

let BIN_OF_BINS = [
  [], // 128 bits each chunk
  [], // 256
  [], // 512
  [], // 1024
  [], // 2048
  [], // 4096
  [], // 8192
  [], // 16384
  [], // 32768
  [], // 65536
  [], // 131072
  [], // 262144
  [], // 524288
  [], // 1048576
  [], // 2097152
  [{ start: 0, count: 100 }], // 4194304
]

console.log("Memory returned:", allocate((128 << 1)));
console.log("Memory returned:", allocate((128 << 1)));
console.log("Memory returned:", allocate((128 << 1)));
console.log("Memory returned:", allocate((128 << 2)));
console.log("Memory returned:", allocate((128 << 2)));
console.log("Memory returned:", allocate((128 << 2)));
console.log("Memory returned:", allocate((128 << 1)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(BIN_OF_BINS, null, 2));
```

How can you make it so it takes two parameters, `allocate(bits, count)`, instead of one, where the `count` parameter tells how many memory slots of `bits`-size to allocate *in advance*?

I have been trying all night but have not ended up with anything that is very close to working, and it's starting to lose its simplicity from the original answer.

```js
// desired count is a power of two only
function allocateBunch(bins, base, size, desiredCount) {
  let desiredFactor = (2 ** (size - 1))
  let totalFound = 0
  let i = 0
  let n = bins.length
  while (i < n) {
    // 1024 4096
    let factor = 1 << i
    let bin = bins[i]
    while (bin.length) {
      block = bin[0]
      let diff = desiredCount - totalFound
      let diff1 = Math.ceil(diff / factor)
      let min = Math.min(block.count, diff1)
      block.count -= min
      totalFound += (min * factor)
      base.push({
        start: block.start,
        count: diff
      })
      block.start += ((min * factor) * (64 << size))
      let done = totalFound >= desiredCount
      if (done) return
      if (done) {
        var bits = (64 << size)
        var remainingUnsedMemory = ((min * factor) - diff) * bits
        var adjustmentSize = bits
        var startBinIndex = i
        var memoryAddress = block.start + (diff * bits)
        while (remainingUnsedMemory != 0) {
          // memoryAddress += adjustmentSize;

          // bins[startBinIndex].push({
          //   start: memoryAddress,
          //   count: 1
          // });
          // startBinIndex--;
          remainingUnsedMemory -= bits;
          // adjustmentSize = bits;
          // bits >>= 1;
        }
      } else {
        bin.shift()
      }
    }
    i++
  }
}

let BIN_OF_BINS = [
  [], // 128 bits each chunk
  [], // 256
  [], // 512
  [], // 1024
  [], // 2048
  [], // 4096
  [], // 8192
  [], // 16384
  [], // 32768
  [], // 65536
  [], // 131072
  [], // 262144
  [], // 524288
  [], // 1048576
  [], // 2097152
  [{ start: 0, count: 100 }], // 4194304
]

let base = []
allocateBunch(BIN_OF_BINS, base, 1, 4096)
allocateBunch(BIN_OF_BINS, base, 1, 8192)
console.log(BIN_OF_BINS, base)
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is this. Say you want to allocate 100, 1000, or 4096 (to pick some numbers) blocks in advance (following the linked question for context, or the first algorithm above). You have `BIN_OF_BINS` which starts out with a top-level value indicating some memory available. You subdivide this as necessary to get the desired blocks, but don't need to actually recursively subdivide stuff, you can take shortcuts. You can do some calculations to tell how far to jump. But having trouble getting there.

If the blocks (after many additions/removals, or allocate/frees) are scattered all over the place, the algorithm ideally would still be able to collect a bunch of blocks in a certain size so they are ready to be plucked.

For example: if I ask for 1 block of size 512, I should get:

```
[
  [],
  [],
  [ { start: 0, count: 1 } ],
  [ { start: 1024, count: 1 } ],
  [ { start: 2048, count: 1 } ],
  [ { start: 4096, count: 1 } ],
  [ { start: 8192, count: 1 } ],
  [ { start: 16384, count: 1 } ],
  [ { start: 32768, count: 1 } ],
  [ { start: 65536, count: 1 } ],
  [ { start: 131072, count: 1 } ],
  [ { start: 262144, count: 1 } ],
  [ { start: 524288, count: 1 } ],
  [ { start: 1048576, count: 1 } ],
  [ { start: 2097152, count: 1 } ],
  [ { start: 4194304, count: 99 } ]
]
```

If instead I make a request for 8192 512 bit values, I should have:

```
[
  [],
  [],
  [ { start: 0, count: 8192 } ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [ { start: 2097664, count: 1 } ],
  [ { start: 4194304, count: 99 } ]
]
```

Comment: In last example, it is not correct. 8192 x 512 = 4194304 so you are left with the following change [ { start: 4194304, count: 99 } ] and everything else is []. 512 x 2048 is probably what you meant and this would give you the 3 entries of those size. However, rather than placing bin[2][{start:0, count: 2048}] it places it in bin[13][{start: 1048576, count: 1}], which is the same size just different bin. Start being 1048576 or zero makes no difference as long as the return value is one of the two and different to the one being stored. Updated my answer to calculate the memory offset backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated version, memory offset calculation is now going backward instead of forward.

```
let FRAGMENTED_BINS_OF_BIN = [
    [], // 128 bits each chunk
    [], // 256
    [], // 512
    [], // 1024
    [], // 2048
    [], // 4096
    [], // 8192
    [], // 16384
    [], // 32768
    [], // 65536
    [], // 131072
    [], // 262144
    [], // 524288
    [], // 1048576
    [], // 2097152
    [{ start: 0, count: 100 }], // 4194304
  ];
  
  function allocate(binDataSource, bits, quantity) {
    var requiredSize = bits * quantity
    if (requiredSize < 128 || requiredSize > 4194304) {
        throw "Bits required out of range";
    }
  
    var lastBin = binDataSource.length - 1;
  
  
    for (var binIndex = 0; binIndex <= lastBin ; binIndex++) {
        var bin = binDataSource[binIndex];
  
        //
        // We have found a bin that is not empty...
        //
        if (bin.length != 0) {
            //
            // Calculate amount of memory this bin takes up
            //
            var thisBinMemorySize = (128 << binIndex);
  
  
            for (var b = bin.length - 1; b >= 0; b--) {
                var blockOfInterest = bin[b];
                var blockSize = blockOfInterest.count * thisBinMemorySize;
                //
                // We've found a continous block this bin that fits the amount we want
                //
                if (blockSize >= requiredSize) {
                    //
                    // We are going to return this block
                    //
                    var allocatedMemoryBlock = {start : blockOfInterest.start, count : quantity, bits : bits};
  
                    //
                    // Figure out how many blocks were consumed...
                    //
                    var blockConsumed = Math.ceil(requiredSize / thisBinMemorySize);
                    var totalMemoryConsumed = thisBinMemorySize * blockConsumed;
                    //
                    // Perfect amount, so delete whole block from bin
                    //
                    if (blockConsumed == blockOfInterest.count) {
                        bin.splice(b);
                    }
                    else {
                        //
                        // Otherwise count reduced by consumed block amount and the start address is adjusted to account for consumed block
                        //
                        blockOfInterest.count -= blockConsumed;
                        blockOfInterest.start += thisBinMemorySize * blockConsumed;
                    }
  
                    //
                    // We may have acquired more memory than we need so we need to put the excess back into their respective bins...
                    //
                    var leftOverMemory = totalMemoryConsumed - requiredSize;
                    if (leftOverMemory > 0) {
                        //
                        // adjust the left over memory start address by the amount we have actually used
                        //
                        var leftOverMemoryAddressStartsAt = allocatedMemoryBlock.start + requiredSize;
                        var endOfMemory = allocatedMemoryBlock.start + totalMemoryConsumed;
  
                        while (leftOverMemory != 0) {
                            //
                            // Previous bin... size and index
                            //
                            thisBinMemorySize >>= 1;
                            binIndex--;
  
                            //
                            // This unused block fits in this bin...
                            //
                            if (leftOverMemory - thisBinMemorySize >= 0) {
                                //
                                // Register it...
                                //
                                endOfMemory -= thisBinMemorySize;
                                binDataSource[binIndex].push({start : endOfMemory, count : 1});
  
                                //
                                // Reduce the amount of left over memory...
                                //
                                leftOverMemory -= thisBinMemorySize;
                                leftOverMemoryAddressStartsAt += thisBinMemorySize;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return allocatedMemoryBlock;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false; // failed to find any sizable blocks
  }
  
  function freeMemoryBlock(memoryBlock) {
    var bits = memoryBlock.bits;
  
    delete memoryBlock.bits;
  
    var belongsToBin = Math.log2(bits >> 7);
  
    FRAGMENTED_BINS_OF_BIN[belongsToBin].push(memoryBlock);
  }
```

Comment: Can this be reworked to not have two separate bins? Because your continuous bin will become fragmented if we return those items to memory. Ideally it would search through to find a large enough bin given some calculation, the regular bin.

Comment: Memory freed never get put back on to the continuous bin. It always get put back on the fragmented bin. When you allocate 128 bits for the first time, using the original method you fragment the remaining memory (4194304 - 128) into 15 bins. This method, when you allocate 128 bits, the continuous bin, now have (4194304 - 128) without splitting that up so it doesn't get fragmented. The only way the continuous bin can get fragmented is when the block is small and it start slicing it from the next block. When that happens you could move it from continuous bin to bin[0] and set count accordingly

Comment: Edited answer to handle single bin. Regarding last paragraph of previous comment, you don't have to set count, it would be correct already.

Comment: I am not sure this has the same output as the previous answer if `quantity = 1`. I replaced some code that had some tests and tests aren't passing. I also am using different data structures than the array so it's a bit more complicated, but the essence is there. It seems as though around `var leftOverMemoryAddressStartsAt`, it is different than before. Here, I am using `allocate(bins, 512, 1)` and getting `binIndex == 14 and leftOverMemoryAddressStartsAt == 512`, so `binDataSource[binIndex].push(...)` is pushing a start address at the wrong size (512 for bin 14).

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/7b7351cc81764b37590fb5e9c0d81931) is an example demonstrating the errors.

Comment: First example looks perfect to me. You allocated 512 bits, and that allocation starts off at address 0. The address is then adjusted by 512. Bin 15, memory address starts at 512, and this bin size is 2097152. So I adjust memory by 2097152 which gives 512 + 2097152 = 2097664, bin 14 start address is 2097664.

Comment: But the blocks should stay aligned to values of their size. So they should always fall on one of the markers. I [updated](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/7b7351cc81764b37590fb5e9c0d81931) with another (and better) data. So the last block only can have values falling on `4194304`, `4194304 * 2`, `4194304 * 3`, etc, the second to last at values `2097152`, `2097152 * 2`, `2097152 * 3`, etc., otherwise they will get misaligned and freeing will become a problem / more complicated. This is what I meant by "dividing" the blocks in half, they always stay on the half alignment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229292/discussion-between-john-and-lance-pollard).